# How to make Plotly JS dynamically use the full height / width of a div, without hardcoding pixel dimensions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, plotly, plotly.js

When clicking on the top button, the size of the container `#myDiv` changes. How to make that the Plotly automatically takes all the available size of the container, **without any noticeable delay**?

Here there is some high delay:

```js
var z = [], steps = [], i;
for (i = 0; i < 500; i++) 
    z.push(Array.from({length: 600}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)));  
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    steps.push({ label: i, method: 'restyle', args: ['line.color', 'red']});
var data = [{z: z, colorscale: 'YlGnBu', type: 'heatmap'}];
var layout = {title: '', sliders: [{
    pad: {t: 5},
    len: 1,
    x: 0,
    currentvalue: {xanchor: 'right', prefix: 'i: ', font: {color: '#888', size: 20}},
    steps: steps
  }]};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
document.getElementById('button').onclick = () => { 
    document.getElementById('myDiv').classList.toggle('size2');
    Plotly.Plots.resize('myDiv');
}
```

```css
#button { background-color: gray; }
#myDiv { width: 500px; height: 300px; border: 2px solid black; }
.size2 { width: 300px !important; height: 200px !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.16.2.min.js"></script>
<span id="button">Click here to change the size</span>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<div id="text">Hello world</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make Plotly automatically take all the available size of the container, you can use the 'autosize' option in the layout object.

```js
var layout = {
    title: '',
    autosize: true,
    sliders: [{
        pad: {t: 5},
        len: 1,
        x: 0,
        currentvalue: {
            xanchor: 'right',
            prefix: 'i: ',
            font: {
                color: '#888',
                size: 20
            }
        },
        steps: steps
    }]
};
```

Comment: Welcome on SO and thanks for your answer. Can you edit your post to include a runnable code snippet? It's useful to test quickly a JS solution.

Comment: I tested, it doesn't work: nothing gets resized.

Comment: Have you tried the responsive option? Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [], {}, { responsive: true }). Per the Plotly documentation, "If you set the responsive attribute equal to true (using the config object), then your figures will be automatically resized when the browser window size changes. This is an especially useful feature for charts which are going to viewed on mobile devices!" Source: https://plotly.com/javascript/responsive-fluid-layout/